# How do a string comparison on two columns from two tables in Oracle SQL with PHP

Tags: php, oracle

So I have these tables:

```
SQL> select * from project;

PNAME              PNUMBER PLOCATION             DNUM
--------------- ---------- --------------- ----------
Virtualization          40 Houston                  5
CRM                     50 Stafford                 4
Bladeservers            60 Houston                  1
ProductX                 1 Bellaire                 5
ProductY                 2 Sugarland                5
ProductZ                 3 Houston                  5
Computerization         10 Stafford                 4
Reorganization          20 Houston                  1
Newbenefits             30 Bellaire                 4
9 rows selected.

SQL> select * from dept_locations;

   DNUMBER DLOCATION
---------- ---------------
         1 Houston
         4 Stafford
         5 Bellaire
         5 Houston
         5 Sugarland
        30 Norfolk
        30 Suffolk

7 rows selected.
```

I need to make a new column ptype that checks the plocation and the dlocation and sets ptype to LOCAL if any department location matched for the dnum in the project, otherwise the result should be REMOTE. Any clues on how to do this? Thanks,

Comment: Use a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: you might need to use update statement for the old data. But for new data that come in you can set a trigger after insert and then set it like you want